# Library to create high-performance server applications

Tags: linux, high-load, c10k

I remember finding a C++ (or maybe plain C) library which does thread pooling, socket polling and other stuff, needed to write a high-performance server on Linux. (And this library was not [Boost](http://boost.org) itself — but it could be that it used Boost.)

As usual, I can't remember the name of the library. Any guesses?

**Update:** that was *not* [ACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Communication_Environment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spserver](http://code.google.com/p/spserver/) uses libevent and so should have good performance on all platforms.

You could use [Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html) directly and thread pool:

> Multiple threads may call io_service::run() to set up a pool of threads from which completion handlers may be invoked ...  all threads that have joined an io_service's pool are considered equivalent, and the io_service may distribute work across them in an arbitrary fashion.

Comment: Hurray! That was SPServer I was thinking about! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [ACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Communication_Environment)?

Answer (score 1):

[POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)?  [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/)?  Got any further clues?

Comment: Sorry, not POCO nor libevent. But thanks for the links anyway!